# CSS: Vertical List with vertical sublist

Tags: html, css, sublist

Is anyone able to recommend a change to my HTML/CSS that will push the lower list items down, rather than the current behavior which places the submenu on top of them?

My JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arq2j/

CSS:

```
#navcontainer ul { list-style-type: none; }

.nested
 {
     display: none;
     list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    position: relative;
}
li:hover > .nested
 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    top: 0;
}​
```

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the `position: absolute;` lines? http://jsfiddle.net/Arq2j/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes:

Remove the height on the main ul:

```
ul {
 font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial;
 font-size:20px;
 /* height:36px; */
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
 width:20%;
}
```

Remove the absolute positioning on the sub ul:

```
ul li:hover ul {
 display:block;
 height:auto;
 /* left:0;
 position:absolute;
 top:36px; */
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/Arq2j/2/ for a working example.